# Provider hosted sharepoint add ins windows + forms + anonymous authentication

Tags: sharepoint-2013, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I created a provider hosted sharepoint add ins that works with windows authentication. It asks 2 times to enter credential, 1st when logging to sharepoint and 2nd while connecting to app server from the sharepoint. it works after I enter both. Now I also need to allow access to add ins to certain people who have forms authentication in sharepoint. How can I achieve this ? and Can I make the app server not prompt the credential and work with anonymous authentication ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.